# pyspark - compare two String col and show the diff in new col

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, data-quality

I am doing some data quality checking,
How do I compare two StringType columns ('old_unmatch' and 'new_unmatch') and create new columns for the results ('new_unmatch' and 'missed_unmatch)?

| old_unmatch | current_unmatch | new_unmatch | missed_unmatch |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ['121', '122'] | ['121', '123'] | ['123'] | ['122'] |

Comment: Hey I actually created a library: https://github.com/SuperiorityComplex/data_checks where you can just write Python code to do exactly that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compare two string columns in `PySpark` and create new columns to show the differences, you can use the `udf` (User-Defined Function) along with the `array_except` function.

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, array_except
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType

# Create a SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

# Sample data
data = [
    (['121', '122'], ['121', '123']),
    (['124', '125'], ['124', '125']),
    (['126', '127'], ['127', '128'])
]

# Create a DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['old_unmatch', 'current_unmatch'])

# Define a UDF to compare two arrays and return the differences
def compare_arrays(old_arr, current_arr):
    return list(set(old_arr) - set(current_arr))

# Register the UDF
compare_arrays_udf = udf(compare_arrays, ArrayType(StringType()))

# Add new columns to the DataFrame
df = df.withColumn('new_unmatch', compare_arrays_udf(df['old_unmatch'], df['current_unmatch']))
df = df.withColumn('missed_unmatch', compare_arrays_udf(df['current_unmatch'], df['old_unmatch']))

# Show the resulting DataFrame
df.show(truncate=False)
```

or

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import array_except

# Create a SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

# Sample data
data = [
    (['121', '122'], ['121', '123']),
    (['124', '125'], ['124', '125']),
    (['126', '127'], ['127', '128'])
]

# Create a DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['old_unmatch', 'current_unmatch'])

# Add new columns to the DataFrame
df = df.withColumn('new_unmatch', array_except(df['current_unmatch'], df['old_unmatch']))
df = df.withColumn('missed_unmatch', array_except(df['old_unmatch'], df['current_unmatch']))

# Show the resulting DataFrame
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Output-

```
+------------+----------------+-----------+---------------+
|old_unmatch |current_unmatch |new_unmatch|missed_unmatch  |
+------------+----------------+-----------+---------------+
|[121, 122]  |[121, 123]      |[122]      |[123]          |
|[124, 125]  |[124, 125]      |[]         |[]             |
|[126, 127]  |[127, 128]      |[126]      |[128]          |
+------------+----------------+-----------+---------------+
```